# iOS objective c framework not working in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I wrote the objective-c framework and build it with connect my iphone in Xcode, when add this framework to my project and run with iphone 8 simulator I got an error that for x86 architecture.

how can I fix this error?

P.S: I want to framework works with both device and simulator.

Comment: Did you add the product framework to your project's embedded binaries?

Comment: @David Yes David.

Comment: Are you sure your framework support x86_64 and i386? Use `lipo -info` to check it

Comment: @Tj3n how can check with lipo? I've got no input files specified error

Comment: Under Build active arch. - Debug - make it YES. And under Valid Arch. remove x86_64 i386 arch. then clean and build.

Comment: @vivekDas not working for me

Comment: From the warning i can see you have two copies of your framework, just check in your project and remove one which is not required.

Comment: Go inside your framework file then use `lipo -info` on the `.a` file inside to check, your framework probably didn't built with x86_64 arch thats why you got the error, this is not related to your app

Answer (score 2):

It's not about your app target, but `TestFrameWork.framework`.

Check the architecture of the `TestFrameWork.framework` with this command in terminal:

```
lipo -info /path/to/TestFrameWork.framework/TestFrameWork
```

It outputs the arch list there. If you could build your apps with this framework in the iOS real device, it must contain the `armv7 armv7s arm64` inside, that's the iOS device's environment used.

For the iOS Simulator, it uses your nested macOS environment `i386 x86_64`. If you have the `TestFrameWork.framework` source code, compile it in both in iOS simulator and iOS device, use `lipo` command to merge them into a fat one. If you get the `TestFrameWork.framework` from your partners or vendors, send a request to them for this. Every iOS library developer shall know this, I think.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your framework doesn't support i386 architecture.
You need no create a universal framework.

Check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@nishantnitb/writing-custom-universal-framework-in-xcode-9-and-ios-11-7a63a2ce024a).